# Mercurial and online sharing - how to proceed

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, codeplex

A noob question... i think

I use Mercurial for my project on my laptop. How do i submit the project to an online server like codeplex?

I'm using tortoisehg and i cant find the upload interface for submit the project online...

Answer (score 2):

From the command line, the command is:

```
hg push <url>
```

to push changes a remote repository.

In TortoiseHg, this is accessed through the "Synchronize" function, which seems to show up if you right-click in a Windows Explorer window but not on any file. It's also available in the workbench; the icon is 2 arrows pointing in a circle.

Answer (score 0):

For these things, I find the best way to go is to use the command line interface - TortoiseHG is OK if you need to perform some common operations from the file browser, and it's a nice tool to visualize some aspects of your repository, but it doesn't implement all of mercurial's features in full detail, and it renames and bundles some operations for no apparent reason.

I don't know how things work at codeplex, but I assume it is similar to bitbucket or github, in which case here's what you'd do:

- Create an empty repository on the remote end (codeplex / bitbucket / ...).
- Find the remote repository's URL - for bitbucket, it is https://bitbucket.org/yourname/project, or ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/yourname/project.
- From your local repository, commit all pending changes, then issue the command: `hg push {remote_url}`, where `{remote_url}` is the URL of the remote repository. This will push all committed changes from your local repository to the remote repository.

Since the remote's head revision (an empty project) is the same as the first revision in your local copy (because all hg repositories start out empty), mercurial should consider the two repositories related and accept the push.

For an introductory guide to command-line mercurial, I recommend http://hginit.com/